# How to dynamically change value in .volt on screen view

Tags: javascript, php, phalcon, volt

I am using phalcon, .volt template

I am getting some data from database(predictability). Svg has one line starting on line 0 and finishing on 30.
Another line is draw about first line and it should display some predictability

My problem is that it doesn`t look nice on small screens and I would need to change (only for mobile views 30 to 20)

I know that php itself can`t detect screen size as javascript (window.innerWidth);

```
<svg >
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0"  />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{{ predictability * 30 / 100 }}" y2="0"/>
</svg>
```

Is it possible somehow integrate JS to .volt and dynamically change fixed number 30 ?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxyse.png)

Comment: PHP is a server side language, it don't know nothing about your screen, you must use javascript to handle any modifications into browser, and redraw window with results provided by frontend operations or requesting to server, so php can perform tasks and bring it back to frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them work together. Let's suppose you are using Micro in Phalcon and you have defined the `view` service:

1. Create in your router the path:

   ```
   $app->get('/view/home2/{size}',
     function ($size) use ($app) {
        echo $app->view->render('index/home2', 
             [
              'svgWidth' => $size
             ]);
     }
   );
   ```
2. Create view '/index/home2':

   ```
    <svg >
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="30" y2="0"  />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="{{ predictability * <?php echo $svgWidth; ?> / 100 }}" y2="0"/>
    </svg>
   ```

In your 'index/home' page, at the beginning:

```
<script>
   let url = window.innerWidth < 999 ? '/view/index/15' : '/view/index/30'; //or set a switch with more options for predictability value
    window.location.replace(url);
</script>
```